# Internet Explorer "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch" on local files (no server)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, web

I'm developing an application which creates a HTML report at the end, it outputs the js and css files separately then loads the files normally. But Internet Explorer 8-10+ refuses to load the CSS files due to "*CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch*", but of course, the MIME can't be modified, as they are local files and **not** being served by a server.

So in short:

- Local files (C:\,file://,etc)
- CSS Won't load due to "MIME type mismatch"
- Works in every other browser without issue -_-
- Not "http://" or "localhost" or any variant

**So, does anyone have any idea's on a work-around for this issue?**

HTML loading of CSS:

```
<head>
    <title>Results</title>
    <link href='resources/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='resources/bootstrap-responsive.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='resources/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>    
</head>
```

**Note**:
According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the fix is: "*Ensure style sheet file is delivered with the proper HTTP response header, which includes a content type of text\css. See MIME-Handling Changes in Internet Explorer for more information.*", but obviously impossible, as no header's are being sent across the wire......

Comment: You're not using Notetab Light are you?

Comment: Nope, Notepad++ though, but found the issue.... (See answer below)

Comment: Just a recommendation if you are doing lightweight web development on windows, WebMatrix. It is a free web IDE that includes a development web server. http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: Ahh, my lightweight web development app of choice is XAMP, but nah, this HTML file had to be NOT served by a Server, but a local file (was going to be opened on "users" computers which may or may not have internet access)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the issue by testing on a few different machines, it turns out if you have a CSS file set to open with a particular program, it will prevent IE from loading, and will give the above error message -_-

Also mitigating the potential problem by including a CDN version of the CSS at the end of the file (the report has to work with and without internet)

Comment: When you say local files, you mean running from the local file system right? (no http:// in the address bar)

Comment: I've just came to bump into this problem. I hate IE sooo much you can't imagine.

Comment: It is a rather annoying problem :/ Viva La IE :(

Answer (score 8):

I'm on Windows 8.1 using IE11 with the same issue. This is how I fixed it:

1. On your computer search for "regedit.exe" (go to the start menu and click on the search button on the top-right corner of the screen).
2. Once regedit opens up, on the left column click on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" and then on ".css"
3. On the right column double-click on "Content Type". This will open up a dialog box.
4. In the dialog box change "value data" to "text/css".
5. Click "Ok" and that's it.

I hope this helps other people out there.

Comment: Indeed this solved the issues with CSS files loaded locally. Had same issue with Windows 7, IE 10.

Comment: Works fine. The value was set to "application/x-css" on two clients and "text/css" on all others. Does anyone know why the value differs? However, IE doesn´t throw this mismatch error if you have "Display intranet sites in Compatibilty View" option enabled, but I don´t recommend setting this option.

Comment: Mine was already set to "text/css" and I'm still getting the error on Windows 10, IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Tomcat and JSP. 
I had to put : <%@page contentType="text/css" %>  at the top of the CSS file and then tomcat serves it as a CSS mimetype.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the folder where  CSS hosted had different permission than page where CSS needed to be applied. I changed to same permission and worked.

Comment: That's not an answer. Use the comments field instead.

Answer (score -2):

Kyeemagh, 23 May -14

Hi to all of you who have the problem with Internet Explore that showing "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch" on local files (no server).

I have Win7 with IE11 and i found the solution by doing 2 days searching in the Internet... with many coffees.

Please click on the first link then scroll down to the "3 Answers" and read the instructions how to solve the problem! In my laptop works ok.

[CSS not rendered in IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974731/css-not-rendered-in-ie-10)

and then for original information and ownership click on:

http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

I hope it helps.

Eventually I can see correctly all my web pages that I'm making, from my C: driver - no server, on the IE11 browser.

Remember to have the correct coding in your html page at  section, that link to an external css file.

- Please pass it to anyone who need this particular free help!

with many thanks,

Dionysios

Comment: While this link may fix the problem, please provide the necessary information here directly, as it pertains to this problem. Ideally, without the long backstory