# Correct way to set Content Type for css file?

Tags: asp.net, content-type, mime

My site(built with asp.net) renders fine in all browsers except IE8 + 9. The IE dev-tools tells me that some CSS was ignored due to MIME type mismatch.

After some research I found out that it´s probably because of me not setting the content type of my css-files correctly. I´m not sure how to do this either, but setting the type property of my link does not seem to cut it:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
```

I´ve check my IIS settings and "text/css" is included in the MIME-types.

Comment: Might be of use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473610/internet-explorer-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-on-local-files-no

Comment: Thank you, but my site is not local.

Comment: Contact whoever is hosting your site, and ask them to confirm if CSS files are configured to open with a Windows program by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your css files are set to open with a windows program by default. Remove that default in windows and IE 8-9 should work.