# CSS not attaching locally

Tags: html, css, windows, internet-explorer, web

I've got a new laptop from work, I took it home over the weekend to start a new website for a client. 
I built the index.html and styles.css in Brackets. Hit the preview (chrome) button - looks great. I opened the working folder and tested in the 'Fox - fine. 
Tested in IE - no styles... Checked my code, looks fine (plus it works in other browsers) checked IE dev tools, the DOM explorer shows the  for the style sheet, but no styles are present in the dev tools Styles explorer.

I asked the techs at work if it might be something to do with the Laptop local profile, but they think not. I have full admin rights and Firewall is off.

Laptop is 64bit Windows 7.

I.E. version 11

We're baffled!

Any ideas?

Thank you, 
Jess

Comment: This question is unanswerable. Without seeing your computer it could be anything. It's also questionable as to whether this is even about programming.

Comment: can you include the top of your HTML file that includes references to your CSS file, does the IE console give you any errors?

Comment: @martpendle yes - error says "mime type mismatch" ? I'll include a snippet when I've get the laptop back, the techs are putting xampp on

Comment: A quick search has pointed me to here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473610/internet-explorer-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-on-local-files-no

sounds more like a PC issue rather than a HTML\CSS issue

Comment: Our tech just found the same article, fixed, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Our Tech has fixed it! FYI he went into reg edit > H Key Classes Root > .CSS > content type > change Value Data to text/CSS

apparently its a Win 7/IE issue

Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

Test it on a live web server (instead of the local machine).  It looks like there might be a misinterpretation of the path to the stylesheet.

Comment: We're just popping xampp on there - I'll keep you posted :)