# Site not loading up - CSS & JS Loading issue on IE 10& 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

My application is a Single Page Application, which has angularjs and HTML5 with CSS as technologies.

Now the login page or application doesnt load up as attached screenshot on **Internet Explorer versions 10 & 11**

[image: IE 11 URL]

I have done the below tasks as per online help:

1. included in my html :

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge";>`

2. Compatibility View Settings:
   included the domain in the compatibility view settings

No luck till now; any ideas for solving it.

P.S: The application works fine on Chrome / FF / Safari

Comment: If you guys can see CSS loads up with Status Code 200 OK but js files are not loading

Comment: Did you try to add this on in your page? 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: Could you check if javascript loading is available? See http://www.technipages.com/internet-explorer-enabledisable-javascript for information on how to check that.

Comment: @Douwe de Haan If that would be the case, than at least the CSS would be loaded properly.

Comment: @DianaR According to the network log it does.

Comment: @Douwe de Haan you are right, my mistake. Was reading in the title, didn't look at the screenshot.

Comment: @DianaR : I added it on my first point but somehow it was not coming on the question now it comes. Yes i have included it

Comment: @DouwedeHaan: I will try that solution on link

Comment: @GOK, I can see it after edit. Than it is left only the javascript enable to be verified.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan: Now the site loads but with distorted version of it. Below is console error: SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch - File:vendor.css

Comment: How can i resolve this issue programatically rather than changing the browser settings as multiple clients using the system will not be always going and changing the settings :D

Comment: Wow, didn't expect that error. Had that same error myself, got a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473610/internet-explorer-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-on-local-files-no this part.

Comment: You could use <noscript> tags to let people know that they need to activate their javascript. I know some people or administrators like to turn off their javascript because of security issues, but it is a pretty important part of the internet nowadays.