# Invalid argument when running Angular 5 app on IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

My Angular 5 app works fine when I publish and run the PROD build using Chrome, however, I keep getting the `Invalid argument` error when I run the app on IE11. The error message gives no indication on where/cause of the error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

** I'm using the Angular coreUI template.

### [image: Error displayed in IE11 console window]

**Update**

As per @Melchia, i updated the polyfills and generated a new build. When I run the app on IE i see the following errors on the console and the page does not load.

[image: Error on console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install polyfills in order to run your application in IE. 
Go to `src/polyfills.ts` and replace its content with the following:

```
import 'core-js/client/shim';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'classlist.js';  
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'web-animations-js';  
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Then run the following commands:

```
$ npm install --save classlist.js
$ npm install --save web-animations-js
```

For more information about Angular browser support you can check the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

Comment: after configuring the polyfills.ts i'm having an issue loading the app (picture added to desc)

Comment: Now, It's a completely different issue refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473610/internet-explorer-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-on-local-files-no